# Remove localStorage on closing browser javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I found most answer using `window.onbeforeunload` to handle browser closing. But it also does action when refreshing browser. I just want to remove my localStorage when browser closed not refreshing.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Storage) object instead of `localStorage`.

`sessionStorage` is cleared automatically when the browser is closed.

It works in pretty much the same way as localStorage:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("Test", "Test");

var item = sessionStorage.getItem("Test");
```

Comment: Oh yeah, but in `sessionStorage` will clear the data when the tab closing. I just want to clear on closing browser. How can I avoid that problem?

Comment: @Nothing Closing the tab essentially is closing that browser instance (depending on the browser anyway) so I don't see how you can get around that. Do you just want the localStorage empty when the user next visits the site? If so, you could clear it then instead?

Comment: What I am doing, is `add to cart`, storing `item object` in the web storage. So if the user still active on a browser even they are open multiple tab or closing tabs(but not close browser), the item object still in the storage.

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking to store some data that you will be using only for that particular session say user login then you need to use sessionStorage but if your requirement is that you want to allow the user to open multiple tabs then SessionStorage will not work because sessionStorage is not shared across tabs, for this you will need to use localStorage.

Be sure to keep a count of the number of tabs opened and closed and clear the localStorage when the last tab is closed.

Comment: Yeah, what a nice idea! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are looking for is [sessionStorage](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-webstorage-20130730/#the-sessionstorage-attribute) not [localStorage](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-webstorage-20130730/#dom-localstorage)